# How to design an experiment to test the effect of a drug on subjective energy level

Tags: self-study, t-test, experiment-design

I am currently running an experiment to test the effect of a drug (ALCAR) on my energy level (measured using a subjective 5-point scale). My goal is to determine whether or not consuming this drug causes an increase in my energy level. I am taking four measurements at different times (08:00, 12:00, 16:00, 20:00) every day. Each treatment (ALCAR and placebo) will go on for 28 days. If it helps, my data looks like this.[image]

I'm planning on using a t-test to calculate a p-value for the results. However, I'm uncertain about some of the details. **Should I use a matched-pairs design, or a 2-sample design? Should I use n=112 (since there are four measurements per day) or n=28 (using the average of the day's four measurements for each data point)?** I'd like to have as much power as possible without using invalid methods.

Comment: The way I understood your experiment, you will test on yourself the placebo and the drug in two different periods of time. However, I'm sorry to say this, but you will not be able to distinguish the effect of the drug with the effect of the date (perhaps the weather in middle of May was more suited to you than the weather in mid April; or you got better sleep in April because the nights were quieter; or perhaps something very good happens to you only in one of the periods). And I'm assuming that you do not know if now you are taking the placebo or the drug...

Comment: This is not a matched pair design, since the day of sample is confounding factor, as mentioned above.  You will also need to consider what is a positive result.  If treatment "A" causes a boost in a morning and then a crash in the evening, this that better than an average energy across then entire day?  Consider how your scoring method will handle this.